# SQL - Multple Tables - Always return either data or null

Tags: mysql, sql

Really struggling with something I think should be quite simple.  Have been unable to find an answer searching.

I have 4 tables from 4 independent data loggers.  Each table has a time index column and then a series of coulmns with the data channels for that logger.

I need to query all 4 tables to return the row that matches a given time index.  However it is possible one (or more / or all tables) do not have that index in the time column.  In that case I need the query to return null for each of the data columns from that table.

So if each table has 3 channels of data, the query will always return 13 columns (time, 12 channels) where each of the 12 could be data, or null.

Table 1

```
   +------+-------+-------+-------+
    | time | chan1 | chan2 | chan3 |
    +------+-------+-------+-------+
    |    1 |    10 |    20 |    30 |
    |    2 |    11 |    21 |    31 |
    |    3 |    12 |    22 |    32 |
    +------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table 2

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| time | chan1 | chan2 | chan3 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 |   100 |   200 |   300 |
|    3 |   120 |   220 |   320 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table 3

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| time | chan1 | chan2 | chan3 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 |  1000 |  2000 |  3000 |
|    3 |  1200 |  2200 |  3200 |
|    4 |  1300 |  2300 |  3300 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table 4

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| time | chan1 | chan2 | chan3 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
|    1 | 10000 | 20000 | 30000 |
|    4 | 13000 | 23000 | 33000 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

So if i SELECT with time = 1 as the input it should return:

```
1,10,20,30,100,200,300,1000,2000,3000,10000,20000,30000
```

time 2 should return:

```
2,11,21,31,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
```

time 3 should return:

```
3,12,22,32,120,220,320,1200,2200,3200,null,null,null
```

time 5 should return:

```
5,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
```

Thanks

Comment: Some simple sample data and desired results would help.  Are you always expecting exactly 4 rows?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data and desired result.

Comment: You should investigate 'left outer joins'.

Comment: sorry the formatting is poor, I have added sample data and required output as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to join all columns of the loggers to one row for the time, if logging data is present. Somehow like this:

```
SELECT t.time,
       l1.*,
       l2.*,
       l3.*,
       l4.*
       FROM (SELECT '2018-06-05T06:05:18Z' time) t
            LEFT JOIN logs1 l1
                      ON l1.time = t.time
            LEFT JOIN logs2 l2
                      ON l2.time = t.time
            LEFT JOIN logs3 l3
                      ON l3.time = t.time
            LEFT JOIN logs4 l4
                      ON l4.time = t.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` and `union all`:

```
select *
from (select ? as timeindex) t left join
     dl1
     using (timeindex)
union all
select *
from (select ? as timeindex) t left join
     dl2
     using (timeindex)
union all
select *
from (select ? as timeindex) t left join
     dl3
     using (timeindex)
union all
select *
from (select ? as timeindex) t left join
     dl4
     using (timeindex);
```

This assumes that the columns are exactly the same and in the same order in the four tables.

The `using` clause allows the use of `select *`.  It will include the times index defined in the subquery, even when there are no matches.